# Parsing a Blank in SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have  parameters like so:

```
     @P1 NVARCHAR(15) = ''
   , @P2 NVARCHAR(10) = Null
   , @P3 CHAR(1)
```

Now I want to dynamically set the report name base on parameters selected.

- If @P3 = A and @P1 <> "" then ReportName1
- If @P3 = B and @P1 = "" & @P2 <> Null then ReportName
- if @P3 = C and @P2 = Null and @P1 = "" then ReportName

I got number three to work but not list one and two. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this expression in your SQL-query:

```
case 
    when @P3 = 'A' and @P1 <> '' then 'ReportName1'
    when @P3 = 'B' and @P1 = '' then 'ReportName2'
    when @P3 = 'C' and @P2 is null and @P1 = '' then 'ReportName3'
end
```